# Too many }’s. Latex error: \begin{document} ended by \end{table}. EXTRA \endgroup

Tags: overleaf, thesis, report

In main.tex

```
%  $Description: Thesis
%  $Author: xxx $
%  $Date: xxx  $
%  $Revision: 0.0 $

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}{./}} % To include images in other directories
%\usepackage{setspace}

\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup%
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[#1]{#2}\endgroup}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\onecolumn
%--------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
```

In chapter2.tex

```
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
\textbf{Parameters}&
\textbf{Ground WSN}& 
\textbf{Underwater WSN}\\ \hline
Communication Modality & Radio waves & Acoustic waves  \\ \hline
Channel Propagation Speed & 300,000,000 m/s & 1,500 m/s \\ \hline
Transmission Range & 10 to 100 m & Up to 10 Km \\ \hline
Energy consumption & Low comparatively & High comparatively \\ \hline
Memory capacity  & Small  & Large \\ \hline
Cost & Cheap & Expensive \\ \hline
Frequency & 908 to 928 MHz & 10 Hz to 100 KHz \\ \hline
Node Mobility & Application based & Mobile \\ \hline
Node Density & Dense & Sparse \\ \hline
Link Reliability & Application based & Low \\ \hline
Link Stability & Stable & Unstable \\ \hline
Path  Loss & Low & High\\ \hline
Noise Impact & Low & High \\ \hline
Data Flow Mode & Full Duplex & Half Duplex \\ \hline
Flow and Error Control Protocol & Selective Repeat ARQ or Go-Back-N ARQ & Stop-and-Wait ARQ \\
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:table:1}
\caption{Difference between WSN and UWSN}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please make a full (minimal) working example, preferably in a single file. Remove as many packages as you can, that have no role in the issue. Your `table` code compiles fine for me. PS: Have you simply forgotten `\end{document}`?

Answer (score 3):

- from your code fragments is not possible to compose MWE (Minimal Working Example) which will be source of your problems
- error is caused somewhere in your document outside of table code fragment

Some off-topic remark:

- table width is bigger than `\text width, consequently your table protrude right text area border
- to prevent this you need to prescribe columns width with for example `p{\dimexpr\linewidth/3-2\tabcolsep}<width>}` or simpler use `xtabular` or `tabularray` packages which enables automatic calculation of column width.
- by use `tabularrray` package table code is short and clear
- for writing of quantities I suggest to use `siunitx` package

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}    % it load siunitx package

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{group-separator={,}}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {X[l, m] X[l, m] X[l]},
              row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
             }
Parameters
        &   Ground WSN
                &   Underwater WSN      \\
Communication Modality 
        & Radio waves
                & Acoustic waves        \\
    Channel Propagation Speed
        & \qty{300 000 000}{\metre\per\second}
                & \qty{1 500}{\metre\per\second}    \\
Transmission Range 
        & \qtyrange{10}{100}{\metre}
                & Up to \qty{10}{\kilo\metre}       \\
Energy consumption 
        & Low comparatively
                & High comparatively    \\
Memory capacity  
        & Small & Large                 \\
Cost    & Cheap & Expensive             \\ 
Frequency 
        & \qtyrange{908}{928}{\mega\hertz}
                & \qty{10}{\hertz} to \qty{100}{\kilo\hertz}    \\
Node Mobility 
        & Application based 
                & Mobile                \\ 
Node Density 
        & Dense & Sparse                \\ 
Link Reliability 
        & Application based 
                & Low                   \\
Link Stability 
        & Stable & Unstable             \\ 
Path  Loss 
        & Low   & High                  \\ 
Noise Impact 
        & Low   & High                  \\
Data Flow Mode 
        & Full Duplex 
                & Half Duplex           \\ 
Flow and Error Control Protocol 
        & Selective Repeat ARQ or Go-Back-N ARQ 
                & Stop-and-Wait ARQ     \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Difference between WSN and UWSN}
\label{tab:table:1}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

If you for a some reasons persist that text in table cells are centered, than for column specification use `colspec = {X[c, m] X[c, m] X[c]}`. Then resulted table is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with the table is that there's no guarantee that its width will fit inside the text block. Indeed, using the LaTeX default margin settings, the table is too wide. To fix this problem, I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment and allow automatic line breaking in the first two columns.

Two additional suggestions: (a) In order to give the table a more open and inviting "look", please get rid of all vertical rules and most horizontal rules. (b) I'd recommend left-aligning rather than center-aligning the cell contents.

If you want to be able to cross-reference the table, the `\label` statement has to come after, not before, the `\caption` statement.

I've inserted further suggestions and comments as comments in the code below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
%%%\usepackage{epsfig}   % superseded by 'graphicx' package
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%%%\usepackage{latexsym} % superseded by 'amssymb' package
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}{./}} % To include images in other directories
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
%%%\usepackage{graphicx} % don't load packages more than once
%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%%\usepackage{times} % 'times' package is obsolete
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % Times Roman-clone text and math fonts

%%%\usepackage{blindtext} % not needed here

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}
%% Don't modify the low-level \baselinestretch parameter directly:
%%%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2} 

%% is the following really needed?
\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup%
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[#1]{#2}\endgroup}


% New code:
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' column type
%% 'L' col. type allows both automatic line breaking and hanging indentation:
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}

%%%\onecolumn % really??

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
%%%\begin{center} % not appropriate
%%%\centering     % not needed
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LL l @{}}   %%%{ |c|c|c| } 
\toprule % Use fewer, but well-spaced horizontal rules
%% No need for vulgar bold-facing in header cells:
%\textbf{Parameters}&\textbf{Ground WSN}& \textbf{Underwater WSN}
Parameters & Ground WSN & Underwater WSN \\
\midrule
%% I've commented out all 14 [!] remaining \hline directives:
Communication modality & Radio waves & Acoustic waves  \\ %\hline
Channel propagation speed & 300,000,000 m/s & 1,500 m/s \\ %\hline
Transmission range & 10 to 100 m & Up to 10 km \\ %\hline
Energy consumption & Low comparatively & High comparatively \\ \addlinespace %\hline
Memory capacity  & Small  & Large \\ %\hline
Cost & Cheap & Expensive \\ %\hline
Frequency & 908 to 928 MHz & 10 Hz to 100 KHz \\ %\hline
Node mobility & Application based & Mobile \\ \addlinespace %\hline
Node density & Dense & Sparse \\ %\hline
Link reliability & Application based & Low \\  %\hline
Link stability & Stable & Unstable \\ %\hline
Path loss & Low & High\\ \addlinespace %\hline
Noise impact & Low & High \\ %\hline
Data flow mode & Full duplex & Half duplex \\ %\hline
Flow and error control protocol & Selective Repeat ARQ or Go-Back-N ARQ & Stop-and-Wait ARQ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

%%% ALWAYS place \label after, ot before, \caption:
\caption{Differences between WSN and UWSN} \label{tab:table:1}
%%%\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```